# how to find the dimension of the image of $f$ in this case?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Let $A \in M_{m \times n}(\Bbb R)$ be fixed, and let $B \in M_{m \times l} (\Bbb R)$.  Consider the map $f: M_{n \times l}(\Bbb R) \to M_{m \times l}(\Bbb R)$ defined by
>   $f(X) = AX + B$
>   for all $X \in M_{n \times l}(\Bbb R)$.  Find the vector $B$ such that $f$ is a linear map.  For such $B$, find the dimension of Im$(f)$.

please help me. How to find that?

I found out $B = 0$, but I suspect my result.

Comment: What are your thoughts on the problem?  What have you tried so far?

Comment: At the very least, are you able to find $B$?

Comment: I found out B = 0 but I suspect my result.

Comment: @user203060 Don't be afraid: if $f\colon V\to W$ is linear, then $f(0)=0$. Since in your case $f(0)=B$, a necessary condition for $f$ to be linear is $B=0$. If $B=0$ it's easily seen to be linear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct in noting that the map is linear if and only if $B = 0$.

**Hint**: Take any $X \in M_{n \times l}$. Let $x_1,\dots,x_l$ be the columns of $X$.  We can write
$$
AX = \pmatrix{Ax_1& Ax_2&\cdots& A x_l}
$$
So, we can write 
$\operatorname{im}(f) \cong 
\underbrace{\operatorname{im}(A) \oplus 
\operatorname{im}(A) \oplus \cdots \oplus
\operatorname{im}(A)}_l$

Comment: Did you understand my hint?  Did you find the answer, then?